# Как изменить время посещения на сайте с помощью Cookies?

Tags: cookie

Приветствую! Интересно, зарегистрировался я на сайте, например в онлайн магазине. Как можно изменить в куках время, проведенное на сайте? Некоторый сайты принципиально отменяют заказ в связи с тем, что человек сразу зашел на сайт, не провел там и 2 минут, купив товар. Лепят отмену или какие то проверки.

Comment: Ни как. Нормальные сайты не хранят данные в куках на стороне пользователя, кроме идентификатора сессии.

Comment: Хорошо, а со стороны клиента это вообще как то реализовать возможно? Не через куки?

Comment: простите, но вы что-то абсурдное спрашиваете. 1 - если на сайте что-то сделано вот так, с чего вы решили что можете как-то повлиять на это поведение в своем браузере? эта логика заложена на сайте, на сервере. 2 - хотя, эта логика, конечно, по какому-то дикому стечению обстоятельств, может быть реализована на клиенте. но нам это откуда знать? вы же не называете никаких сайтов. а сайты, они, понимаете ли, не одним кодом сделаны.

Comment: "Некоторый сайты принципиально отменяют заказ в связи с тем, что человек сразу зашел на сайт, не провел там и 2 минут, купив товар. Лепят отмену или какие то проверки." идиотская реализация антифрода

Comment: Спасибо всем, форумчане! Еще вопрос, могут ли какие то различные онлайн магазины смотреть на то, когда была установлена системе, когда был установлен браузер ?